# FragmentPagerAdapter, why do I need getPageTitle()

Tags: android

For my TabLayout, I've got this FragmentPagerAdapter:

```
    package de.financeplanner.util.adapter;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import de.financeplanner.fragment.OverviewFragment;

/**
 * Created by Christian on 20.01.2017.
 */

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final int OVERVIEW = 0;
    private final int REVENUES = 1;
    private final int EXPENSES = 2;
    private final int CATEGORY = 3;
    private final int PAGE_COUNT = 4;

    private final String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Übersicht", "Einnahmen", "Ausgaben", "Kategorie" };

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        super(fragmentManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch(position){
            case OVERVIEW: return new OverviewFragment();
            case REVENUES: return new OverviewFragment();
            case EXPENSES: return new OverviewFragment();
            case CATEGORY: return new OverviewFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

}
```

Without this:

```
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        // Generate title based on item position
        return tabTitles[position];
}
```

I've getting an error every time. To be exact, I get this Exception:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Class java.lang.Object.getClass()' on a null object reference

Why is this so? I can't understand, why I need to get the page title, because the process, I think, is in the `getItem(int position)` method.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and show us which line causes the exception.

Comment: Ok, sorry but I've really fixed the problem, only with adding getPageTitle(int position). I've deleted  it and restart the app, now it works also without this method.I saw that I need the getPageTitle(int position) anyway, for displaying the titles inside the TabItem.

Comment: that might stop the exception but it does not really solve the problem

Comment: There is no exception and the application runs without any erros, maybe the restart of the IDE solved the problem

Comment: I am referring to the exception in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your direct question, `getPageTitle()` is used to set the text shown on the tab in a `TabLayout`.

Note that

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    Fragment fragment;
    switch(position){
        case OVERVIEW: return new OverviewFragment();
        case REVENUES: return new OverviewFragment();
        case EXPENSES: return new OverviewFragment();
        case CATEGORY: return new OverviewFragment();
    }
    return null;
}
```

can be simplified to

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return new OverviewFragment();
}
```

Of course, in a real app, you most likely want to create a different fragment for each tab. So keeping the current structure is fine if you haven't got that far yet. At the very least, you should remove the unused declaration `Fragment fragment;`.